# Use Excel conditional formatting based on display value and not cell value

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have a cell with the following conditions to compare its value against the cell in the previous row.

Red Highlight: `Cell Value <> =OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())),-1,0)`

Green Highlight: `Cell Value =  =OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())),-1,0)`

This works well, except for if I use a formula in the cell. When I do, the first highlight (red) is always chosen. I'm guessing because the "value" of the cell is the formula, and not the result of the formula.

```
Example:
 A1 := =24
 A2 := =DEC2HEX(36)
```

`A2` would be formatted "red", despite both cells displaying the text "24".

**Is it possible for conditional formatting to compare based on the displayed text in the cell, and not the underlying formulas?**

Comment: you could use `=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1))=A2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you want to check the cell above in a conditional formatting formula, you don't need that complicated Offset/Indirect construct. Just select A2 and in your conditional format formula reference A1 as a relative reference, i.e. without any $ signs. Then apply that conditional format to other cells and it will always evaluate the cell one row above the current cell.

Getting back to your question: no, the format of a cell is not important. Conditional formatting will evaluate the underlying value.

In the case of `=DEC2HEX(36)`, though, the output is not a number, the comparison will return FALSE if this cell is compared with the numeric value in A1.

Comment: Is there a way to change the comparison so that `DEC2HEX(36) = 24` evaluates to be `TRUE`?

Comment: You need to coerce the text into a number: `=(DEC2HEX(36)+0)=24` returns TRUE, but Hex 24 is not equal to 24, so that will not make sense.

Comment: I ended up just adding a second comparison and letting them fall through. One compared `TEXT(Above, "0")` and the other compared just `Above`.